# Regex to test if '*' is at the end of string if it occurs

Tags: regex

Hi I'm not great with regex and struggling a little here.  I want to test a string and see that when it has '*' in it, that it has only one and it is the last character in the string.

so for example

```
'jflkasjkdfjkslf'  // matches because it has no *
'*'                // matches because it has a * and it is last character
'sdkfjksajdflkj*'  // matches because it has a * and it is last character

'jasldk*aksjdf'  // doesn't match because it has a * and it is not in last position
'asdjflkasjfd**' // doesn't match because it has more than one *
'asdjf*lkasjfd*' // doesn't match because it has more than one *
```

what I have so far is this  `(\*)$`  which is only testing that it ends in *, so I'm pretty far off... :(.

Thanks!

Comment: Something like `^[^*]*(\*)$`?

Comment: The alternative would be to get the index of `*` in the string and check if it isn't there (e.g. the index is -1) or it is at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[^*]*\*?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZXAClP/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%5E*%5D*%5C*%3F%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^*]*` - 0 or more chars other than `*`
- `\*?` - an optional `*`
- `$` - end of string